# How to convert white pixels black background to black pixels white background?

Tags: opencv

I have an image with white pixels and black background. I want to convert it to white background and black pixels using opencv

Comment: `img = 255-img` if img is the loaded image of type CV_8U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bitwise_not` is the function that you're looking for. It negates each bit of each value in the matrix resulting in negation of the colors. So white pixels turns black and black pixels turns white. See [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0002cf8b418479f4cb49a75442baee2f) for details